# python with open invalid argument windows

Tags: python, windows, file

```
import datetime
import os
import sys
import time

if "ZLOG_FILE" not in globals():
    global ZLOG_FILE
    script_dir = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]).replace(sys.argv[0], "")
    ZLOG_FILE = os.path.join(script_dir, "log", datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
    with open(ZLOG_FILE, "w"):
        pass

def log(level, msg):
    with open(ZLOG_FILE, "a") as f:

        # Fix colors
        if level == "INFO":
            msg = "ESC[37m[INFO] " + msg

        elif level == "WARN":
            msg = "ESC[33m[WARN] " + msg

        elif level == "ERROR":
            msg = "ESC[31m[ERROR] " + msg

        if level != "ERROR":
            print(msg)
        else:
            sys.stderr.write(msg)
        f.write(msg)
```

I made this simple logging library that on the first import makes a new file with current time and date in a log directory in the same location as the main script being run. I get the following error however:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>                                           
    import zlog                                                                 
  File "C:\Users\zane\Desktop\zlog.py", line 10, in <module>                    
    with open(ZLOG_FILE, "w"):                                                  
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\zane\\Desktop\\log\\09-12-2016
 20:02:26'
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Got rid of the script name with the script_dir variable, and fixed the formatting on the if statements. Im still getting an error though

Comment: You're treating `test.py` as a directory, which it probably isn't.  (It's right there in the error message.  How could you miss it?)

Comment: Your ERROR logic doesn't make sense. "if level is an error then, if level is not an error?"

Comment: Does the `log` subdirectory exist?  If not, you'll have to create it.  `open()` doesn't automatically create missing subdirectories.

Comment: it exists, I made it manually for the test. Im gonna have add in a way to autogenerate it eventaully though

Comment: Perhaps Windows is objecting to the presence of colons in the filename?

Comment: Wow yeah, I cant use colons. Thats a pain. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Windows cant use colons in file names, and I forgot to remove the main script from the path once I got the directory it was in

Comment: Your system drive is probably NTFS, for which a colon is reserved to specify a [file stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364404) of the form `:stream_name:stream_type`. Opening an NTFS file is actually opening the anonymous data stream, i.e. `::$DATA`. Opening an NTFS directory is actually opening the $I30 index stream, i.e. `:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION`. Directories can also have named `$DATA` streams. In this case "09-12-2016 20:02:26" is invalid because it tries to create a stream named "02" with an unknown stream type "26".